# ELMAH page refreshing

Tags: asp.net, elmah, page-refresh

I've integrated ELMAH log checker in my web application. 
Actually the web application consists of 4 tabs, one of them is ELMAH log checker.
When I go ELMAH tab, and then change the tab to another, it refreshes the page after couple of minutes. I'm using ELMAH module first time, so I don't know , is it normal , that the page is refreshing itself after going to ELMAH tab or no.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal expected behavior. It refreshes so you can see new reported bugs as they come in.

I would recommend iframing Elmah on the tab, then the refresh won't affect the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I will follow Your advice. :)